# How can I remove all newlines from hash values?

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I tried removing all newlines (`\n`) from the values of a hash:

```
my %var_h = (  "ID"   => " This is Test 
                           This is new line TEST 


                           newline Test end ");
```

How can I remove all the new lines from the values of `%var_h`?

I tried `s/\\n//g` but I could not get it to work.

Comment: I now see by the way that your problem was that you were escaping '\n' when you didn't want to be. (Unless this is a typo in the question.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
s:\n::g for values %var_h;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I'm absolutely shocked that this works (in that values does not copy) but I just tested it with a simpler example.

Comment: @Unknown Google: yes, values does not copy and for will alias to them.  keys does copy, though.

Answer (score 4):

What are you running the substitution against? You seem to want to fix only the values, so I would use the [`values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) keyword:

```
for my $value (values %var_h) {
  $value =~ s/\n//g;
}
```

An alternative (at OP's request) would be to use map and a slice though I find it a lot less clear:

```
@var_h{keys %var_h} = map { s/\n//g } values %var_h;
```

Comment: is there any other to way to do this

Comment: I added a second method. But do you want a method without using `values` at all?

Comment: @var_h{values %var_h} needs to be @var_h{keys %var_h} - also, I'm not sure if keys and values are guaranteed to return in the same ordering...

Comment: @ ijw - Stupid of me, thanks for the catch. I believe that they return in the same order, but I will have to check that.

Comment: @ ijw - keys, values and each are guaranteed to return in the same order. See perldoc -f values|keys|each

Answer (score 3):

All other solutions remove \n from all values of hash.

I'm not sure if this is required.

So to remove only from this one value you have:

```
$var_h{'ID'} =~ s/\r?\n//g;
```

Technically s/\n//g should be sufficient, but I have the habit of adding \r? before it, so it will handle Windows-styled new lines as well.

Comment: It's a good point. I was assuming that the one value was just an example and that he might not know in advance which values had or didn't have unwanted newlines.

Comment: How can the extra characters get in there?

Comment: Elves? I didn't give much thought to _how_ the newlines got there. Off the top of my head: bad user input, a regular expression capture gone wrong, sheer cussedness and programmer error.

Comment: @Telemachus I am asking about the magical extra \r's. The OP's requirement was to remove \n's.

Comment: @Sinan: Genuine Advantage Elves, in that case

Comment: Actually to be fully correct s/\r\n?|\n//g; i.e. \r\n, \r, \n

Comment: Well, since both "\r" and "\n" can be replaced by '', then it's simpler to just write: s/[\r\n]+//g - it will work the same way.